# AutoHotkey: Disable Ctrl+Shift (Windows 10 - keyboard layout switch)

Tags: autohotkey, windows-10-desktop

How can I **disable** the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> hotkey (keyboard layout switching) in Windows 10 using AutoHotkey?

(However I would like to **keep** all combinations of this:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>*Any other key*</kbd>)

I've tried this, but it's not blocking the hotkey:

```
; Test.ahk
; Try disable Ctrl+Shift
+^::
```

**Edit**: 
I've found a way to disable it in newer Windows 10 builds without AHK:
https://superuser.com/a/1322396
But I think the question is still standing.

Comment: On Windows 10 go to  Settings->Time & Language->Language->Keyboard.
Click on the link "Input language hot keys" and change or remove the "Key sequence Between input languages"

Comment: To disable Ctrl+Shift using AutoHotkey add the hotkey `<^Shift::return ; do nothing "<^" means LCtrl`to your script.

Answer (score 16):

Write this in your execute prompt (using <kbd>Window + r</kbd>):

```
rundll32 Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL input.dll,,{C07337D3-DB2C-4D0B-9A93-B722A6C106E2}{HOTKEYS}
```

it will show you the panel directly so you can disable the hotkey in the change key sequence button. I think it works in any windows edition. :D

Answer (score 1):

```
Click "Clock, Language, and Region" from the control panel
Click "Language"
Click "Advanced settings" in the right column
Under "Switching input methods", click "Change language bar hot keys"
Select "Between input languages" and click "Change Key Sequence"
Disable/change the keyboard shortcut as you'd like
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/2hBSM6r.png - I don't know where did they hide it this time... I'm tired of hunting for this option.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/3Mgx2XU
  If you search for language it should pop up

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/unable-to-remove-a-language-from-windows-10-april/47c13ea5-79ed-4a29-96d4-47d1264b6838